# Can't Autowired MockMvc using @WebMvcTest

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, mockmvc

I'm trying to test my REST Controller in my Spring Boot application. This is my test class

```
import com.binar.kelompok3.secondhand.repository.OffersRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockBean;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

@WebMvcTest(HistoryController.class)
public class HistoryControllerTest {

    @MockBean
    private OffersRepository offersRepository;

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;    

    @Test
    void signIn() throws Exception{
        mockMvc.perform(get())
    }
}
```

When I put `@Autowired` on the MockMvc field Intellij gives me `Could not autowire. No beans of 'MockMvc' type found` and the `mockMvc.perform` method doesn't work.
I've tried changing `@WebMvcTest` to

```
@SpringBootTest
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
```

But Intellij still gives me

```
Could not autowire. No beans of 'MockMvc' type found
```

when I hover my cursor on `mockMvc`

How can I autowired MockMvc? Thanks

Comment: What versions of Spring Boot and IntelliJ are you using? If you are using Spring Boot 2.7, you need IntelliJ 2022.1.3 or later. See https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-289633 for details.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson I'm using Spring Boot 2.7.0 and Intellij 2021.3.3. I'll try to update to the newer version and see if it works

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just needed to update Intellij to 20022.1.3