# Could not autowire. No beans of 'MockMvc' type found - Imported correctly, configured correctly and works fine in other project?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, testing, mockito

In my Controller test class I am trying to test use Mockito and MockMVC to test the controller layer independently.
I have reused code from my previous project but for some reason it is not working in this new project despite containing identical configuration, imports etc.

```
   import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.AutoConfigureMockMvc;
    import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcTest;
    import org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockBean;
    import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
    import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;

import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.post;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status;

@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@WebMvcTest(controllers = UserController.class)
public class UserControllerTests {

    @Autowired
    MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    private UserService userService;

    @MockBean
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Test
    public void FindPlayersSuccessfully() throws Exception {

        String json = "{\"userID\":\"1\"}";

        mockMvc.perform(post("/api/v1/users/find-users")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .content(json).characterEncoding("utf-8"))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.response").value("Success"));
    }
```

The 'MockMvc mockMvc' autowire is highlighted in red by IDEA and when I hover over the error it says 'Could not autowire. No beans of 'MockMvc' type found'

Also, something possibly strange I noticed is that when I added imports one by one, the MockMvc import did work and the highlight disappeared, but when I added the:

```
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcTest;
```

import, the problem occured.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Try add @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)

Comment: Are you using Spring Boot 2.7? If so, this looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73085049/cant-autowired-mockmvc-using-webmvctest.

Answer (score -2):

I had the same problem. Try in Intelij Idea File-> Settings->Editor->CodeStyle->Inspections, then choose Spring Core -> Code and change "Incorrect injection point autowiring in Spring bean components" severity from Error to Warning.